# Can not match mobile nos using PHP

Tags: php

I am facing one issue .I am trying to match two mobile no using PHP but it is not giving the output as per expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$mobile="09029704634";
$mobj="+919029704634";
if(strpos($mobj,$mobile)){
    $flag=1;
}else{
    $flag=0;
}
echo $flag;
?>
```

See here both mobile are logically same. One has `0` in beginning and another has `country code +91` in the beginning. Here I need if both no are logically same it should return 1 otherwise 0.Here any country code can come not only `+91` .Please help me.

Comment: Well then OBVIOUSLY a straight `strpos` is not going to be enough.

Comment: What about the number length? Are they always made up of 10 numbers?

Comment: length may b anything I can assume all mobile no from all country.

Comment: Another question, will the mobile number start with 0 other than the 0 added intentionally for global calling?

Comment: Strikes me that you should have captured the parts more carefully and stored them in seperate fields/columns then you could compare them more easily/accurately

Comment: It may/may not starting from 0. Here my need is i have to check the both numbers logically same or not.

Comment: You have to define the logic with constraints. There is no magical logic in any programming. If you have no idea about the input variations, you cant catch all scenarios. Simple as that.

Comment: Phone numbers can be tricky ... checkout **[this library](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php)** if you want a quasi-definitive solution.  A 800 pound gorilla to smash a fly, but rather complete.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of mobile number varies across the globe, this might be a good option that can be tried out. Strip all 0s at the beginning.

Usually a 0 is added for national calls, and 00 for international calls. So ltrim any + or 0 at the beginning of the number, and do a `strpos()`

```
<?php

$mobile="09029704634";
$mobile= ltrim($mobile,'+');
$mobile = ltrim($mobile, '0');
$mobj="+919029704634";
if(strpos($mobj,$mobile)){
    $flag=1;
}else{
    $flag=0;
}
echo $flag;
?>
```

Looking for feedbacks, if this is inefficient.

**ADD:** If the both comparing operands interchange in their formats, or isnt predictable, then the only way you have is to get hold of all country codes from a database, compare the operands by stripping country codes or appending them, doing multiple checks to finally deduce if they are same logically or not.

Comment: Ok,your code is working fine for this condition but see here i added this line `if(strpos($mobj,$mobile) || strpos($mobile,$mobj) || $mobile==$mobj){` and just reversed the value `i.e-$mobile="+919029704634",$mobj="09029704634";`. In this case not working.

Comment: Here i am validating all cases so that no matter which variable hold which value both should be logically same.

Comment: You will then have to have a database of all country codes, try appending them and strip them from the operands to finally check if its same or not logically.

Comment: In my case i can not same all mobile no. Those are fetched  and I have to compare and I also don’t require to save. Here I added like `$mobj=ltrim($mobj, '0');` and I think its working fine.